# When does Soundcloud provide additional access?

Tags: soundcloud

Soundcloud API has 15K play limit. When does Soundcloud provide additional access?

Soundcloud API has 15K play limit. When does Soundcloud provide additional access?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits#play-requests

Rate limits are reset every 24 hours and code to handle hitting the limit is provided.

Comment: But I find that Soundcloud API do not have 15K limit recently. What is happen?

Comment: But I thought i answered the question asked exactly.